# How can I set the height of an option?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a list of options but the box is larger than needed. How can I adjust the position/height to match the old layout?

current implementation:

[image]

Code:

```
<div>
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-2">Match Type</div>
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <div>
    <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="singleRecordMatchBean.matchType">
      <option value="undefined" [disabled]="true" >---Select---</option>
      <option *ngFor="let object of defaultOptions.MATCHES" [ngValue]="object.code" 
      >{{object.desc}}</option> 
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2" style="color: red; font-size: 0.93em;white-space: pre-wrap;">*Required</div>
```

desired outcome:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Design the `option` element by Height and width in css.

```
option{
      height: 10px;
      Width: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Target the `select` element via css, (add another class to the html element and reference it in the CSS file) then set `height: desiredvalue`. Check if `min-height` is set to the element, if so, unset it.

Be aware that the `form-control` class is already applied, which is bootstrap style, that might interfere with your style. Inspector tools will be of help here.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `height` and `width` of your object in the CSS file

```css
#dropdown{
    width: 250px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">Match Type</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
         <div>
           <select id="dropdown" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="singleRecordMatchBean.matchType">
             <option value="undefined" [disabled]="true" >---Select---</option>
             <option *ngFor="let object of defaultOptions.MATCHES" [ngValue]="object.code" 
             >{{object.desc}}</option> 
           </select>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2" style="color: red; font-size: 0.93em;white-space: pre-wrap;">*Required</div>
</body>
</html>
```